# Get Selected Value of DX PieChart using seriesClick

Tags: charts

I am using DX Charts version 14.1. I have built a simple piechart and need to get the clicked value from the pie chart. I tried to use the seriesClick, but it returns the entire series. I have no idea which part was exactly clicked on the pie chart. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Instead of using the seriesClick, we need to use the pointClick function. Hope this helps somebody.

```
pointClick: function(point)
{
    console.log(point.argument);
}
```